# I cant see Desktop icons option in appearance settings, and icons are gone

Tags: gnome, 22.04, icons

In ubuntu settings, appearance I cant seem to find the Desktop icons option.

[image]

Also my desktop icons are gone. Anyone knows a fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the tool "Extensions", which, if not installed, can be installed with the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs`. Under "Build-in", enable "Desktop Icons NG (DING)". (This can also be done with Extension Manager, package: gnome-shell-extension-manager).

If that extension is not listed, then likely components of the standard Ubuntu desktop have been removed. Check whether either `ubuntu-desktop` or `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` are installed. If not, then install one of the two with the terminal command (for example for `minimal`): `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal`.

If one of these packages are effectively installed, then something must be broken on your system. Then you can try explicitly reinstalling the Desktop icons extension: `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`.

Comment: @24601 I undid your edit: I am referring to the (semi-official) tool "Extensions", not to "Extension manager" . Of course, Extensions Manager can also be used, but the package is gnome-shell-extension-manager. Nevertheless, I now included reference to that tool as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the GNOME desktop to its default settings by opening a terminal and typing the following command:

`dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`

[reference](https://linuxconfig.org/reset-gnome-desktop-settings-to-factory-default-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish)

Comment: Really, really, bad idea. Don't do this.

Comment: @EML perhaps you'd care to explain why...

Comment: It resets everything, from the background image on upwards: fonts, text sizes, dock/etc, just giving you more problems to fix. Better to concentrate on the actual issue.