# Desktop icons not showing in 22.04

Tags: nautilus, 22.04, icons

Desktop icons aren't shown: [i.stack.imgur.com/LGslL.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGslL.png)

I've read [this case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141696/desktop-icons-disappeared-on-ubuntu-18-04), but it doesn't recognize `nautilus-desktop`:

```
username@computer:~$ nautilus-desktop
nautilus-desktop: command not found
```

I do have nautilus installed, though:

```
username@computer:~$ sudo apt-get install nautilus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nautilus is already the newest version (1:42.2-0ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp-server2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libgnome-bg-4-1
  libntfs-3g89 libvncserver1 libwinpr2-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
```

The "Desktop" directory exists with its corresponded files. It's just not showing in the user interface.

Edit:

```
username@computer:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cant see Desktop icons option in appearance settings, and icons are gone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429990/i-cant-see-desktop-icons-option-in-appearance-settings-and-icons-are-gone)

Comment: @vanadium, no. I don't see a "Desktop Icons NG (DING)" under "Build-in". I've also reset with ``dconf reset -f /org/gnome/``, but Desktop (the UI) remains empty.

Comment: scroll to the bottom of the Extension Manager window and it should be listed under *System Extensions* if not, then select the `Browse` tab and enter `desktop icons NG` and that should find it.

Comment: Don't see anything: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pB8N.png

Comment: [edit] your question with the result of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Your answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429990/i-cant-see-desktop-icons-option-in-appearance-settings-and-icons-are-gone Read more carefully.

Comment: @24601, I've edited the OP.

Comment: @vanadium, I've installed package gnome-shell-extension-manager (which is the second package from that answer), opened it, but "Desktop Icons" is unsupported. I installed it, nevertheless, but no difference.

Comment: You may not have a regular Ubuntu 22.04 system, then. On Ubuntu, Desktop Icons is supported. Again, read the answer there *carefully* and *stepwise*.

Comment: I've read it carefully and stepwise. Desktop Icons (the extension that is released by rastersoft) isn't supported. Only this deprecated version works: https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/4337/desktop-icons-neo/. I'll leave it there, but the classic 22.04 desktop icons aren't available.